# Trying to get Precompiled Headers running with Qt Creator on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, precompiled-headers

As soon as I add PRECOMPILED_HEADER = pch.h to my pro file, I get the fatal error 'debug/Example_Name_x86_64.pch/c_x86_64' file not found.

I also have the lines CONFIG += precompile_header and HEADERS += pch.h in my pro file, is there anything I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve it already?